# Npm errors when installing packages on windows share

Tags: permissions, windows-8, shared-folders, cifs, npm

I have Ubuntu 12.10 running as a VMware guest on my Windows 8 host.

I have shared a folder on my Windows 8 Host and it is mounted in the Ubuntu guest on startup using this entry in `fstab`:

```
//myhost/work /work cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,noserverino,nounix,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The share works fine and is able to be served by a webserver such as nginx.

However, there seems to be issues when I install node.js packages using npm, I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
user@ubuntu:/work/test$ sudo npm install grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
...
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash'
npm ERR! error rolling back  grunt@0.4.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash' }
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../which/bin/which'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd /work/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path ../which/bin/which
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/fixtures/aaa.txt'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd /work/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path /work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/fixtures/aaa.txt
npm ERR! fstream_path /work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/fixtures/aaa.txt
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/test/basic.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd /work/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path /work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/test/basic.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/test/basic.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/work/test/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob/test/00-setup.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
...
npm ERR! not ok code 0
user@ubuntu:/work/test$
```

What could be causing this problem? From the command line, I can `chmod`, `rmdir` among other things using sudo without any issues.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Running with `--no-bin-links` fixed it for me:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

`--no-bin-links` tells `npm` to not create any symbolic links.

Occasionally, for some packages that create symlinks even with the `--no-bin-links` directive, or in the case where using this directive causes other errors, you can remove the symlinks from the package(s) that is showing error with the command:

```
npm unlink <package>
```

There is definitely no way to translate symlinks to a Windows share.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you 200 more times. This makes it possible to use Vagrant on windows.

Comment: npm install --no-bin-link

also works.

Comment: Great answer! But is there a way to make this work with the "devDependencies" of a package.json file from Grunt? That would be awesome :)

Comment: Thank you! Vagrant should put this in their official documentation for Windows. All my points are belong to you.

Comment: I can't run `grunt` with `--no-bin-links`.

Comment: I found a solution to work with gulp and grunt please, read below.

Comment: Thank you, you have saved my day, i was struggling from 1 day

Answer (score 6):

How to allow creating symlinks on windows [this page](http://ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/) helped me a lot which explains that this happens even if your shared folder is writable.

To fix it, you need to enable symlinks feature in VirtualBox.

Run at cmd prompt:

```
VBoxManage setextradata YOURVMNAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/YOURSHAREFOLDERNAME 1
```

Then verify by:

```
VBoxManage getextradata YOURVMNAME enumerate
```

> If your user belongs to Administrators group then start VirtualBox with "Run as Administrator"!
>
> By default Windows 7 security policy does not allow creating symlinks as it's a potential security threat. Run "secpol.msc" and navigate to "Local Policies-User Rights Assignments" and add your user to "Create symbolic links". I didn't try that but could be that after that virtualbox could be run as a regular user.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with lorem, but it's not enough.

1. run Virtualbox 'as an admininstrator' on Windows.
2. make sure you executed: `VBoxManage.exe setextradata YOUR_VM  BoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/YOUR_SHARED_FOLDER 1`

Replace the YOUR_VM and YOUR_SHARED_FOLDER with your values.
You can check the value via: `VBoxManage.exe getextradata boot2docker-vm enumerate`

There is [a virtualbox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085) tracking this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of VirtualBox should allow symlinks if you start VirtualBox as Adminstrator (right click: Run as administrator).

Same applies to vagrant boxes: just run your cmd.exe/PowerShell as admin and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

in [this npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7308) @drmyersii give a great solution, I'll only copy and paste to don't link the answer only.

> The real solution here would be to set your configuration to allow
>   symlinks on Windows hosts in your Vagrantfile. Here's an example
>   (assuming that you are running it in VirtualBox):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end
```

this worked great for me and now I can use gulp with [scotchbox](https://box.scotch.io/).

Answer (score 0):

For me none of these answers worked. I'm not sure why but I believe it's because my share is nfs. So I couldn't get it to allow symlinks even when running as Administrator and changing the setextradata settings. I was working with gulp and some other packages that seem to have [issues](https://github.com/jsBoot/gulp-jsdoc/issues/26) [obeying](http://perrymitchell.net/article/npm-symlinks-through-vagrant-windows/) --no-bin-links. It was STILL trying to create some symbolic links and obviously failing. Finally this [thread](https://github.com/jsBoot/gulp-jsdoc/issues/26) on Github clued me into a "solution", hacky as it may be. I "simply" installed the project in my non-shared folder and set that as my NODEPATH.

```
export NODE_PATH=/home/vagrant/PROJECTNAME/node_modules
```

Caveat is that it will affect the entire server and the workflow of updating/changing the packaging.